# JavaScript : don't know how to progress with the game

Tags: javascript

I'am creating  game however have a problem with finishing some parts and i don't know where to put new codes etc
I want to add to my game the following:
1.Until to the end of game I want to see information about the amount of game left to play in order to win the entire game. I created the button (NewGame) and when i press at that button i put the number  how many rounds i want to play and getting output e.g (You must win 3 rounds to win the game!) however that output is disappearing  when i start the game with pressing e.g 'Paper' button....don't know how to keep that information.
2.After the round that user or computer win the necessary amount of  games I need to display in new line e.g "YOU WON THE ENTIRE GAME!!!"

```js
    //user choice
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var count = 3;
var countUser = 0;
var countComputer = 0;

var button = document.getElementById("newgame");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  game = window.prompt("How many games you want to play?");
  output.innerHTML =
    "You must win  " +
    game + " rounds  to win the game! Choose the button start the game!";
});

var paper = document.querySelector("#paper header");
paper.addEventListener("click", function() {
  paper.classList.toggle("header-special");
  userChoice = "paper";
  output.innerHTML = "You  Chose Paper";
  compareWithComputer("paper");
});

var scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors header");
scissors.addEventListener("click", function() {
  scissors.classList.toggle("header-special");
  userChoice = "scissors";
  output.innerHTML = "You  Chose Scissors";
  compareWithComputer("scissors");
});

var stone = document.querySelector("#stone header");
stone.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stone.classList.toggle("header-special");
  userChoice = "stone";
  output.innerHTML = "You  Chose Stone";
  compareWithComputer("stone");
});

    // Computer choice

function compareWithComputer(userChoice) {
  var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  if (computerChoice == 1) {
    computerChoice = "stone";
  } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }

//compare
  var results = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

  output.innerHTML += ". Computer Chose " + computerChoice + results;
  result.innerHTML = "user " + countUser + "computer" + countComputer;
}
// Compare userChoice and computerChoice
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  }
  if (choice1 === "stone") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      // stone wins
      countUser++;
      return "You win!";
    } else {
      // paper wins
      countComputer++;
      return "You lose! Try again.";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "stone") {
      // paper wins
      countUser++;
      return "You win!";
    } else {
      // scissors wins
      countComputer++;
      return "You lose! Try again.";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "stone") {
      // stone wins
      countComputer++;
      return "You lose! Try again.";
    } else {
      // scissors wins
      countUser++;
      return "You win!";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
.start{
font-size:25px;
color:brown;
 margin:10px;
}
.game {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
max-width: auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
text-align: center;
font-size:40px;
padding:5px
border-radius: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
padding:5px;

}

.header-special {
font-weight: bold;
background: yellow;
}

.newgame {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
max-width: auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
text-align: center;
font-size:40px;
padding:5px
border-radius: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
padding:5px;

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <div class ="start"
    <h1>Click the button, start the NewGame!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="game" id="paper">
    <header>Paper</header>

    </div>
    <div class="game" id="scissors">
    <header>Scissors</header>

    </div>
    <div class="game" id="stone">
    <header>Stone</header>
    </div>
    <div class="newgame" id="newgame">
    <header>NewGame</header>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="result"</div>
```

Comment: We all just lost the game.

Comment: Please post full code and make a snippet

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio savage :D. Anyway, is there any chance you can share a fiddle or something to work with and eventually isolate the problem? currently, it's a quite vague one.

Comment: I think a good starting point would be to declare an "init" function, which resets all variables (count, countUser, countComputer) to their initial value when the button "NEW GAME" is clicked.